# Why is my list not reiterating when I put a double loop on python

Tags: python, list

So I am trying to create a multiplication table from 2 to 9, for some reason when I put a *double for loop* it shows the following. I am thinking it's because, after the initial loop, the next loop simply starts at the [3] instead of [2]. Am I correct? if so, why is that? I thought the iteration should start from [2] element on the second loop and go back to the first loop.

```
numbers = map(int,range(2,10))
for numone in numbers: 
    for numtwo in numbers:
        print('{0}*{1}={2}'.format(numone,numtwo,numone*numtwo))


Result 
2*3=6
2*4=8
2*5=10
2*6=12
2*7=14
2*8=16
2*9=18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because when you use `map`, you're using a iterator. And iterators only go forward. Ever.

There's no need for `map`, you can just use `range`:

```py
numbers = range(2,10)
for numone in numbers: 
    for numtwo in numbers:
        print('{0}*{1}={2}'.format(numone,numtwo,numone*numtwo))
    print()
```

The code above shows the expected output because `range` is an iterable and *can* restart iteration.